# Непонятное отображение подсказки

Tags: javascript

подскажите пожалуйста почему [этот код](http://learn.javascript.ru/play/tutorial/widgets/tooltip-moving/index.html) работает корректно, а [мой](http://prozaik.16mb.com/js/tooltip2/)(принципиально подобный) нет. мой вариант подсказки движется рывками в частности

вот мой код, если лень загружать страничку:

```
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- WIDJET Tooltip IMPLEMENTATION------------
```

function Tooltip(options) {
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ properties ---------- 
    var self = this;

```
var elem = options.elem,
    html = options.html
    offset = options.offset || 20;

var isShow = false;

var bodyTooltip,
    elemCoords,
    cursorLeft,
    winLeft,
    left,
    top,
    winTop;

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ methods ------------      
self.createTooltip = function(){
    if(!bodyTooltip){
        bodyTooltip = $('<div />',{
            class: 'tooltip',
            html: html
        });

        return bodyTooltip;
    }
}

self.appendTooltip = function(){
    bodyTooltip.appendTo('body');

    isShow = true;
}

self.deleteTooltip = function(){
    $('.tooltip').remove();

    isShow = false;
}

self.calculate = function(pageX, pageY){
    var scrollY = $(window).scrollTop();
    var winBottom = scrollY + $(window).height();

    var scrollX = $(window).scrollLeft();
    var winRight  = scrollX + $(window).width();

    var newLeft = pageX + offset;
    var newTop = pageY + offset;

    if (newLeft + bodyTooltip.outerWidth() > winRight) { // если за правой границей окна
      newLeft -= bodyTooltip.outerWidth();
      newLeft -= offset + 2; // немного левее, чтобы курсор был не над подсказкой
    }

    if (newTop + bodyTooltip.outerHeight() > winBottom) { // если за нижней границей окна
      newTop -= bodyTooltip.outerHeight();
      newTop -= offset + 2;  // немного выше
    }

    bodyTooltip.css({
        left: newLeft,
        top: newTop
    });     
}

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ handlers -----------      
self.onOver = function(e){      
    if(!isShow){
        self.createTooltip();

        self.appendTooltip();

        self.calculate(e.pageX, e.pageY);
    }
}

self.onLeave = function(){      
    if(isShow){
        self.deleteTooltip();
    }
}

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ events -------------  
elem.on('mousemove', self.onOver);

elem.on('mouseout', self.onLeave);
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Ваш вариант **не** принципиально подобный. В первом варианте биндятся обработчики на три события, а в вашем нет обработчика на `mouseenter`. 
Обработчик на событие `mousemove` создает и размещает подсказку, а дальше не реагирует из-за строчки.

`if(!isShow){`

Поэтому нет плавного перемещения.